# PIA Outlook Office library

Tags: vb.net, outlook, office-pia

I am having simple question.

I installed PIA Office 15.0 for outllook and gave reference in my winform .net application.

I just wanted to know if I deploy this application on machine which is having lower version of outlook(e.g. outlook 2007/2010) will my application work properly?

Sorry it is 14.0 outlook PIA refernece given by me to my app. and code is

`         Dim OutlookMessage As outlook.MailItem
        Dim AppOutlook As New outlook.Application
        Try
            Dim oApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._Application
            oApp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application

```
        Dim oMsg As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._MailItem
        oMsg = oApp.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem)

        oMsg.Subject = P_Subj
        oMsg.Body = P_Body

        oMsg.To = P_To
        'oMsg.CC = sCC

        If Trim(P_AttachPath) <> "" Then
            Dim sBodyLen As Integer = Int(P_Body.Length)
            Dim oAttachs As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Attachments = oMsg.Attachments
            Dim oAttach As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Attachment

            oAttach = oAttachs.Add(P_AttachPath, , sBodyLen, P_AttachPath)
        End If

        oMsg.Send()
        MsgBox("Mail sent to outlook successfully. ", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "")
        oApp = Nothing
        oMsg = Nothing '
```

it is giving error for office 2007.

Comment: There is no PIA for Office 2013, they've been obsolete for the past 5 years thanks to the superior "Embed Interop Types" feature.  Are you *sure* you are doing this correctly?  And no, you cannot get a warranty here, kaboom if you accidentally used a 2013 feature that wasn't available in an older version.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using PIAs that correspond to the lowest version of Outlook/Office. Thus, you can be sure that you don't use methods and properties introduced in later versions. In general, if you embed interop types (read more below) it will run without issues.

Beginning with the .NET Framework 4, the common language runtime supports embedding type information for COM types directly into managed assemblies, instead of requiring the managed assemblies to obtain type information for COM types from interop assemblies. Because the embedded type information includes only the types and members that are actually used by a managed assembly, two managed assemblies might have very different views of the same COM type. Each managed assembly has a different Type object to represent its view of the COM type. The common language runtime supports type equivalence between these different views for interfaces, structures, enumerations, and delegates. You can read more about that in the [Type Equivalence and Embedded Interop Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997297%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article in MSDN.

Also see [Walkthrough: Embedding Types from Managed Assemblies (C# and Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409610.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Answer (score 0):

I have been using the *Microsoft Office 2010: Primary Interop Assemblies Redistributable* in several of my applications, and I can report that deployment on Windows 8.1/8/7 running Office 2013/2010 is flawless. I have also had some success deploying to XP machines running Office 2003, but this is not guaranteed.
The 2010 PIA Redistributable is available for download at http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3508